# What would be the way to bring the internet to the house from the 4G USB internet stick which is 350 meters away?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, home-networking, fiber

I'm trying to bring internet to a cottage. The only way that the internet provider offers me is through a 4G USB internet stick. However, the problem is that the network signal is very bad in the cottage itself, and therefore the internet connection is also very poor. But at 350 meters uphill the signal is excellent (as is the internet connection).

In general, what devices do I need (on the hill) to connect the 4G USB internet stick and connect to the medium? And which medium would be the best to transmit the data with minimal loss of flow to the cottage? What devices are needed in the cottage itself to receive internet and send Wi-Fi internet?

Comment: Are you OK/allowed to run cable from cottage to uphill? If not I'm guessing you're looking for a wireless solution?

Comment: FWIW, companies that offer 4G USB internet sticks typically offer routers with the same service. The intention with a 4G USB internet stick is a connection to one PC. But the same 4G USB can be delivered via a router.

Comment: FWIW, routers like the TP-Link AC750 accept 3G/4G LTE USB sticks. So getting a router such as that can be a good alternative if the ISP cannot provide you with a 4G LTE router.

Comment: cellular USB sticks don't have good antennas, try a larger stand-alone device (e.g. a router with built-in cellular modem) or a modem with external antenna socket where you can connect a larger directed antenna that is mounted to the outside wall of the cottage.

Comment: Is there power atop the hill? If so, a repeater with narrow antenna might be the least expensive solution.

Comment: @gregg My plan is to definitely bring the power cable to the point on the hill where the assembly would be located. As the site is in the woods, the line of sight to the cottage is poor, so I will have to put a network cable to the cottage. I think an single mode optical cable would be a good solution(to enable transmission of at least 20Mb/s)?

Comment: @Xeron yes, for 350 meters you'll need OS2 Sincle-mode Fiber Optic for outside application (or OM2 or OM4 Multimode Fiber Optic but for 20Mb/s OM1 will probably do as well) but I'm no expert on fiber.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 As I will probably need to run a fiber optic cable to the cottage, does that router have a fiber optic port? If not, is there such a router? Or some device that would allow me to connect a fiber optic cable to the router you mentioned?

Comment: @Robert Do you know maybe a name of router of that kind?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik My plan is to definitely bring the power cable to the point on the hill where the assembly would be located. Is there a possibility that the network signal can be somehow "caught" and forwarded through, for example, a coaxial cable to the cottage? Because i'm not a expert at this field at all, does that network signal have "included" internet signal as well(when it comes to cottage)?

Comment: @Xeron Sorry, no personal experience, I just know they exist. Search for e.g. "LTE router SMA" (SMA is a common antenna connector type).

Comment: You will need to run mains over that length which would probably mean permits etc. A 12v, 2A line over that distance would require something like a 70mm2 cable. It would also have to be buried with the correct certified sheath.

Comment: @Xeron “Or some device that would allow me to connect a fiber optic cable to the router you mentioned?” I have no idea how you went from 4G Internet stick to fiber optic. Such a router does not have a fiber optic port.

Comment: I've had some success building a wireless infrastructure cheaply using Unifi "Litebeam" devices. These are decently simple radios/antennas that can run using PoE and with users reporting strong connections over several hundreds of meters distance, even through strong weather.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so there are various solutions available, including Powerline extenders, repeaters, and wireless bridge devices; however, for the most cost-effective and straightforward setup, I recommend the following, considering I don't know what your budget is for this, and assuming your ISP is not willing to provide you with any further help.

**4G WiFi Router in the cottage with External Antenna on the hill**

You'll have to ditch the 4G USB stick and invest in something like the [TP-Link AC1200 4G+](https://www.amazon.co.uk/TP-Link-Wireless-technology-Configuration-MR500/dp/B09X3HRBZQ/ref=sr_1_2_sspa?crid=1X8RK7S0OXSU6&keywords=TP-Link%2BArcher%2B5G&qid=1699869773&s=electronics&sprefix=tp-link%2Barcher%2B5g%2Celectronics%2C45&sr=1-2-spons&sp_csd=d2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9hdGY&th=1) or a similar home Wi-Fi 4G router. It must take sim card and support an external antenna. If the router comes with its own removable antenna's that screw off, then it should also support an external antenna as well. Place this device inside the cottage, preferably in the middle of the property where the WiFi can broadcast to most of the rooms. However, consider the long antenna cable that will be coming into the cottage as well.

**Directional Outdoor Antenna:**

Select a directional outdoor Wi-Fi antenna compatible with the 4G WiFi router. Choose an antenna with a cable long enough to reach from the top of the hill to the cottage. The [Alfa APA-M25](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Alfa-APA-M25-directional-connector-WL-ANT-157/dp/B00R1PA9EO/ref=sr_1_1?crid=3O9JXGHTGEG9T&keywords=The%20Alfa%20APA-M25&qid=1699869985&s=electronics&sprefix=the%20alfa%20apa-m25%2Celectronics%2C57&sr=1-1) is a cheap choice that should work fine, however, there are many antenna's out there to choose from that offer better signal and frequency range if you want to spend more. Just make sure they support the 4G frequency range in use by your ISP, and keep in mind not all antennas are the same and their frequency range can vary based on the region they were originally manufactured for.

**On the Hill:**

**Mounting the Outdoor Antenna:**

Mount the outdoor antenna at the top of the hill, and make sure it has a clear line of sight to the nearest 4G/5G signal mast in your area. The APA-M25 is marketed for outdoor use, but you might also want to think about an optional [enclosure box](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B07CZ49W1X/ref=sspa_dk_detail_2?pd_rd_i=B07CZ49W1X&pd_rd_w=3v9QZ&content-id=amzn1.sym.84ea1bf1-65a8-4363-b8f5-f0df58cbb686&pf_rd_p=84ea1bf1-65a8-4363-b8f5-f0df58cbb686&pf_rd_r=QTV37SZ0KYBDKZXYF49T&pd_rd_wg=g3N7u&pd_rd_r=3ef0eefb-6bf9-4a42-bb6a-1689f1442a08&s=electronics&sp_csd=d2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9kZXRhaWw&th=1) (choose one that fits) to keep it safe from the elements.

**Long Cable:**

Run a long cable from the outdoor antenna down to the cottage. You definitely want to make sure the cable you purchased is weatherproof. For a 350 meter run, your cable is definitely going to be your biggest expense here, because you have to consider the type and quality of the coaxial cable due to signal loss that can occur over long distance. For a distance as long as 350 meters, you want to consider RG-6 or RG-11 for low-loss results. Always check the specifications of the cable you're purchasing, and consult the retailing professional if you get stuck and need further advice.

**At the Cottage:**

**Connect Cable to the Router:**

Connect the cable from the outdoor antenna to the external antenna port on the TP-Link AC1200 4G+ inside the cottage.

**Power On and Test:**

Power on the router and test the internet connection inside the cottage. Adjust the antenna position as needed for optimal signal strength.

This setup minimizes the need for additional devices and simplifies the configuration. The long cable connects the outdoor antenna at the top of the hill to the router inside the cottage, which then broadcasts WiFi internet for you indoors.

**Preliminary Test on the hill:**

My advice is to do all your testing at the top of the hill before running the long cable down into the cottage.

**On the hill:**

- Point the antenna but do not mount it
- Use a short coax cable to connect the antenna to the router
- Power up the router
- Test you're able to connect to the router WiFi with your mobile phone or laptop
- Run a speed test

**Finally:**

See if the retail professional is willing to let you test the 350 meter cable first. You may still have to pay for it anyway, but they may allow you to return it and try another until you find the one that works best. This way, you can repeat the test at the top of the hill with various coax cable types of that length, ensuring you're keeping them on the roll so you can return it and swap out if necessary.

If the above test succeeds, then you are safe to proceed with the DIY project of doing the long cable run from the hill to the cottage and making it all safe and secure.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Before i go on testing. Do i need to bring electricity on the hill to power that antenna? What is your opinion, is it possible to get
 transmission speed through coaxial cable (of average quality) of at least 20 Mb/s (without additional amplifiers), given the distance of 350 meters? Another thing, does the antenna on the hill necessarily have a line of sight to the repeater? Since when i'm on the hill, I can't see the repeater, but the phone shows me that the signal is very good.

Comment: There are apps you can download on your phone that pinpoint the precise location of your nearest signal tower, so that should help when setting the antenna direction. There are many factors at play. 4G network speed, signal strength, interference and environmental factors such as the weather, but most critical i believe is going to be your coaxial cable quality.  High quality weather proof RG-11 is the best quality for long distance, and is capable of providing well beyond 20Mbps. Assuming all the above conditions are "excellent" you should be able to achieve it.

Comment: The alfa antenna does not require additional power because it is a passive device. It connects straight to the router with one coax cable. You will need power on the hill for the preliminary test when you have the router up there with you though, because the router does require power. If you want, you can invest in a more powerful antenna with a built in amplifier, and these do require additional power. I suggested the Alfa antenna because you say the signal is excellent with a low power 4G USB stick, and so I kept the suggestion as budget friendly as possible.

Comment: The good thing about Amazon is they are very friendly with returns as long as you keep the packaging in its original condition. So you can do a proof of concept test with a very short inexpensive coax cable at the top of the hill first, before you go investing in the long cable.